# SQL Server queries xls file worked yesterday(I swear), now refuses to. 0.o

Tags: sql-server

Hey all, the following select statement used to correctly query an Excel spreadsheet on a 64bit SQL Server 2008 R2, and now provides me with an error.

```
SELECT 
     MPNCode, Supplier, Stock , Price, Manufacturer, [Description]
FROM 
     OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\nCompass\Products\Import\SupplierProducts.xls;HDR=YES',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') WHERE MPNCode IS NOT NULL
```

The error I get is.

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
>   server "(null)" returned message
>   "Unspecified error".
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
>   server "(null)".

I've tried restarting everything and googled the thing to death - somehow something has happened that is preventing this from working.

The file-path/file-name is correct because when I change the path I get a different error message.

Ad-hoc connections are enabled from the surface manager - after this I'm stumped at what the issue could be.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I've struggled with this before. These error messages are completely unhelpful. Are you on a 32 bit server? I seem to remember needing to increase the memtoleave area before. Also if you use Procmon can you get any insight? How far does it get with reading the file?

Comment: It's a 64 bit server. Baffled me completly, eventually went for creating a dtsx package that I can execute from my application instead. Thanks for the ideas, I may try procmon if I have further time for this problem.

Comment: I'd try permissions - try saving the file in a folder off the root of C.

Comment: I've the same issue. I always get this error even after changing the file name to wrong file name!

Comment: @AmirPournasserian dtsx is the only way to go I think

Answer (score 1):

Is the linked spreadsheet opened on the desktop?  What happens if you create a new sheet in the same folder and try to open it instead?

Comment: The error is the same whether the spreadsheet is open or closed.

Creating new sheets in the same folder and using those had no joy either.. *shrug*.. I've found a dtsx package work well for this after a little playing around so We'll use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think SQL Server needs to access to TEMP folders to copy or create some files.
If the folder does not exist or ther SQL Service account does not have enough permission to access the folders, you'll get the exception.

Run [Procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) on the server and execute the query again. You can see what's happening and where the SQL Server wants to access.